# Can we know the naturalSize of a video directly from the file?

Tags: ios

I need the information about naturalSize of the video without playing it in the moviePlayer as my ViewController loads.
I have the file in the device and I know its path I just need to know its naturalSize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, you have to create an AVAsset first and then check its natural size property, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a reference...and here is an example

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithUrl:..];
  CGSize s= asset.naturalSize
```

hope it helps

Comment: and it did help !!!!!! 
If only I had posted this question a month ago we wouldn't have faced so many problems with naturalSize related computations in our project !
I was so much dependent on MPMoviePlayer's naturalSizeAvailableNotification! I had to play the video a bit to get the info!
in iOS5 that was also not working properly !
BIG RELIEF !!!!!

Comment: yea, avfoundation goes a long way if you trying to do stuff with video and audio..